# Issues on Installing a Github Package on Python

Tags: python, git

I am quite new in Github and I would like to install a module

I run this on my cmd:

```
C:\Users\memonkey>pip install git+git://github.com/bitsoex/bitso-py
Collecting git+git://github.com/bitsoex/bitso-py
Cloning git://github.com/bitsoex/bitso-py to 
c:\users\memonkey\appdata\local\temp\pip-a9n7xpt6-build
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\memonkey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-a9n7xpt6-build\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    long_description = open('README.md').read()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 23274: character maps to <undefined>

    ----------------------------------------
 Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in 
 C:\Users\memonkey\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-a9n7xpt6-build\
```

I have no idea what is going on, anybody could help me on this

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on windows, the encoding defaults to cp1252, failing to decode curly quotes in the text: “Major_Minor”..... in the [Notations](https://github.com/bitsoex/bitso-py/blob/master/README.md#notations) Section

So, replacing the curly quotes in the license file with normal ones should resolve this issue. So pls contact the developer of that repo for the fix Or fork that repo on your github, fix the content in Notations section from

```
...as “Major_Minor”. For example: “btc_mxn”
```

to

```
...as "Major_Minor". For example: "btc_mxn"
```

And `pip install` from your repo